# Does AgensGraph support connection pool?

Tags: connection-pooling, agens-graph

In some project, I need to use a connection pool in AgensGraph. 
I found "pgpool-II" and "pg bouncer" that support a connection pool function in PostgreSQL. 
So can I use those modules in AgensGraph without any configuration or specific libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pg extension like pgpool or pgbouncer in AgensGraph, most of extensions are guarenteed but some extensions are not 100%, you need to make sure from AgensGraph provider, Bitnine.

Answer (score 1):

The [Drivine](https://drivine.org/) driver from [Liberation Data](https://liberation-data.com/) automatically provides connection pooling, based on PGPool.

Answer (score 0):

PG-Pool just works fine with the connection pool feature.

As you understand, PG-Pool support connection pool, load balance, auto failover trigger of postgresql and PG-Pool HA by watch-dog.

Among those features, connection-pool, failover trigger and PG-Pool HA work greatly without other library.

However if you are required for the load balancing feature, you should contact to the agensgraph provider for extra support or guide, since the cypher query is not able to get parsed by the original PG-Pool.